# vue input clears on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input that looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="avr" value="{{ arv  | currency}}" v-model="arv  | currency">
```

the data model looks like:

```
data: {
   avr: '', 
}
```

and the data is set on `ready` with a request like:

```
this.arv =  this.meta[i].metadata_value;
```

Now this all works fine and I get the right value in the input, but when you click on the input to change it if you want the input clears completely so you loose the number. Why is this doing that? You should be able to just click and change a number if you want without clearing the input completely.

If I ditch `v-model="arv  | currency"` it works as intend, but then my `Watch` function wont.

Comment: Without the rest of the code, it will be impossible to debug with the available information. Also you have `avr` in data, but `arv` everywhere else. And without `v-model`, there is no model-view binding, and therefore nothing else will work. Can you create a simplified jsFiddle example to reproduce the issue, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currency filter should not be used in the `v-model` and you should probably remove the `value="{{ avr  | currency }}"` because `v-model` will take care of the value.

You could format the request to currency format before assigning it to `var` so your input will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="avr" v-model="avr">
```

then on `ready`:

```
this.avr = formatToCurrencyFn(this.meta[i].metadata_value);
```

Comment: Is formatToCurrencyFn a built in function of Vue.js 1.0?

Comment: This seemed to work for that version of vue. `this.$options.filters.currency(this.meta[i].metadata_value);`